# A for loop creates more integers than expect in bash

Tags: linux, bash, integer-arithmetic

I have two dirs `base` and `to_move`. There are 10 files in `base`, which are named
`0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`, and 3 files, `0 1 2`, in `to_move`. What I want is to move the 3 files in `to_move` to `base`, with their names changed to `10 11 12`.

Inside the dir `to_move`, I run the command

```
tmp=$(ls);for item in ${tmp[@]};do dst=$((item+10));echo $dst $item;done
```

what I got is

```
10 0
11 1
12 2
11 1
20 10
21 11
22 12
23 13
24 14
25 15
26 16
27 17
28 18
29 19
12 2
30 20
31 21
32 22
33 23
34 24
35 25
36 26
37 27
38 28
13 3
14 4
15 5
16 6
17 7
18 8
19 9
```

This makes no sense to me, it seems `$(($item+10))` has some weird effects on `$item`.

Why this happens? And how can I modify the command to get this output?

```
10 0
11 1
12 2
```

Comment: Run your script by https://shellcheck.net

Comment: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: @Shawn I don't understand, what is the problem with my script?

Comment: Can you run `set -x;echo $BASH_VERSION;ls`, before your script ?

Comment: Also note that your tmp variable isn't an array. (And a fixed version shouldn't be using that,, array or not)

Comment: @Shawn Thank you, that link is really helpful~

Comment: I have run your script, whcih produced your expected output.

Comment: @Philippe No, It didn’t work on my Linux machine, the link shared by Shawn resolved my issue.